# Cannot find module 'graphql/validation/rules/PossibleTypeExtensions'

Tags: graphql

I'm in the process of learning about the MERN stack by following this book [https://www.amazon.com/Pro-MERN-Stack-Development-Express-dp-1484243900/dp/1484243900/ref=mt_paperback?_encoding=UTF8&me=&qid=](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484243900)
but even if it is a very recent one (published in 2019) the code examples are a travesty.

Basically when I try to start the server contained in this repo https://github.com/vasansr/pro-mern-stack-2/tree/05.02-graphql-schema-file with the command npm start the app crashes and it returns an

`Error: Cannot find module 'graphql/validation/rules/PossibleTypeExtensions'`

The code in the repo was published directly by the author so I don't exactly know how to solve this, could someone help me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

I am following the same tutorial and it seems to work if you upgrade the graphgql to 14.6.0

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your version`npm i graphql@latest`

Answer (score -1):

reinstal using yarn add graphql and update the dependencies as below

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-server": "^2.13.1",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.13.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "graphql": "^15.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  },
```